# Cannot open a new stage upon clicking another button

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

My current code for button event handling is

```
public void handle( ActionEvent e )
{
    if ( e.getSource() == menuS )
    {
        Label name = new Label( "Name" );
        Label address = new Label( "Address" );
        Button save = new Button( "Save" );
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        ColumnConstraints col = new ColumnConstraints();
        col.setPercentWidth( 50 );
        pane.getColumnConstraints().addAll( col, col );
        pane.add( name, 0, 1, 1, 1 );
        pane.add( address, 0, 2, 1, 1 );
        pane.add( save, 1, 3, 1, 1 );
        pane.add( addressTxt, 1, 2, 1, 1 );
        Scene scene = new Scene( pane );
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle( "Add Student" );
        stage.setScene( scene );
        stage.show();
    }
    else if ( e.getSource() == menuF )
    {
        Label name = new Label( "Name" );
        Label address = new Label( "Address" );
        Button save = new Button( "Save" );
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        ColumnConstraints col = new ColumnConstraints();
        col.setPercentWidth( 50 );
        pane.getColumnConstraints().addAll( col, col );
        pane.add( name, 0, 1, 1, 1 );
        pane.add( address, 0, 2, 1, 1 );
        pane.add( save, 1, 3, 1, 1 );
        Scene scene = new Scene( pane );
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle( "Add Faculty Member" );
        stage.setScene( scene );
        stage.show();
    }
    else if ( e.getSource() == menuEmp )
    {
        Label name = new Label( "Name" );
        Label address = new Label( "Address" );
        Button save = new Button( "Save" );
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        ColumnConstraints col = new ColumnConstraints();
        col.setPercentWidth( 50 );
        pane.getColumnConstraints().addAll( col, col );
        pane.add( name, 0, 1, 1, 1 );
        pane.add( address, 0, 2, 1, 1 );
        pane.add( save, 1, 3, 1, 1 );
        Scene scene = new Scene( pane );
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle( "Add Student" );
        stage.setScene( scene );
        stage.show();
    }
    else if ( e.getSource() == menuEmp )
    {
        Label name = new Label( "Name" );
        Label address = new Label( "Address" );
        Button save = new Button( "Save" );
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        ColumnConstraints col = new ColumnConstraints();
        col.setPercentWidth( 50 );
        pane.getColumnConstraints().addAll( col, col );
        pane.add( name, 0, 1, 1, 1 );
        pane.add( address, 0, 2, 1, 1 );
        pane.add( save, 1, 3, 1, 1 );
        Scene scene = new Scene( pane );
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle( "Add Student" );
        stage.setScene( scene );
        stage.show();
    }
    else
    {
        Platform.exit();
        System.exit( 0 );
    }

}
```

I can't find the issue. The first one opens for student but the ones from there on do not work. Any help? I can't seem to find any other way to make this code function.

Comment: You can debug it by System.out.println(e.getSource()); and System.out.println(menuF);. Is those are same?

Comment: What means "do not work", is there an error message ? If your program exits, it means it did not go in your else statements.

Comment: By does not work, I mean that the program will run but when I try using the actual GUI, only menuS works and opens but the others do not.